# Classic ASP Request.Form not working

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have my 1 form as follows

```html
<form action="ForPT.asp" target="_top" method="post" id="frm1" name="frm1">
    <input type="hidden" id="cname" name="cname" value="<%=cname%>"/ >
     <input type="hidden" id="HDate" name="HDate" value="<%=ReqStartDate%>" />
     <input type="hidden" id="Log" name="Log" value="<%=EventLogID%>"/>
</form>
```

I am trying to get the above 3 values in the ForPT.asp form using Request.Form.But it no way works. The ForPT.asp is as follows.

```
<%@ language="vbscript"%>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <body>    
<%
  dim log, sdate, cname
  log = Request.Form("Log")
  sdate = request.Form("HDate")
  cname=request.Form("cname")

 %></body>
```

I have used Request.Form in few other pages and it is working fine.Please help.

Comment: Are you sure `cname`, `ReqStartDate`, and `EventLogID` have values?

Comment: I second what @Bond said, simple way to check is view the source of the generated page and see if the `<form>` hidden `<input>` have anything in `value`.

Comment: If the values are sent to that page from a form too then have `<input type="hidden" id="cname" name="cname" value="<%=Request("cname")%>"/ >`.

Comment: try to add one more <input type='hidden' id='xxx' name='xx' value='xyz' />, if you can captured this 'xxx' field value at ForPT.asp, then the other fields doesn't have any value.

Comment: Thanks Bond, Lankymart, Shadow Wizard, cyan. I had already checked the values in those variables .But strangely i hardcoded and passed a hidden variable ,after that all the values started coming to the forPT.asp page without making any changes. I dont have any idea what caused it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I can't explain why, but it should work with:

```
Request.QueryString("parameter name")
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one of the possible problem:

```
<input type="hidden" id="cname" name="cname" value="<%=cname%>"/ >
```

it should be:

```
<input type="hidden" id="cname" name="cname" value="<%=cname%>"/>
```

Comment: Bond :Thanks for the reply. I have corrected the end tag now . But it did work today without the change.

Comment: Magic is not part of vbscripting, most likely you did changed something as simple as spacing or apostrophe in wrong place and just did not noticed. Or it could be cached on the server if your server config allow caching. Potentially many reasons what could be wrong.